# Creating a stack in C, getting " error error: expected ')' before '*' token "

Tags: c

Usually I just lurk the forums till I can find a hint to help me out, but for this...I have no idea.

So the relevant pieces of code is

```
struct com_stack
{
  unsigned el_num;
  struct command *st;                                         
  unsigned top;
};
void com_push (com_stack* s,command input)  //error regarding this line
{
  if(s->top == (s->el_num - 1))
  {
    s->el_num+=64;
    s->stk=(command*)realloc(s->stk,sizeof(struct command)*s->el_num);
  }
  s->stk[s->top]=input;
  s->top++;
}
```

I believe I created the struct correctly for a stack that will contain commands. For el_num will later be assigned to be the initial size of the stack, and top is the element number that sits at the top.

I'm not sure if I'm handling my push function correctly.  What I would like to do is send in a pointer of the stack and the single command I'm trying to push in.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use "naked" name of the `struct` in C. Either add a `typedef`, or use `struct com_stack *s`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I just now changed struct com_stack *s, and now I'm getting whole new set of errors.<br\><br\>


expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'command'<br\>

my guess is that I need struct infront of command<br\>

'struct com_stack' has no member named 'stk'<br\>

...<br\>

I get a bunch of these, and I'm not sure what to do.  It's been awhile since I have last coded, and this is confusing.<br\><br\>


Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Your `struct com_stack` *doesn't* have a member named `stk` - it has one named `st`, though.

Comment: <br>Hi, thanks for your reply.  I just now changed struct com_stack *s, and now I'm getting whole new set of errors.<br/><br><br/>


<br>expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'command'<br/>

<br>my guess is that I need struct infront of command<br/>

<br>'struct com_stack' has no member named 'stk'<br/>

<br>...<br/>

<br>I get a bunch of these, and I'm not sure what to do.  It's been awhile since I have last coded, and this is confusing.<br/><br><br/>


Thank you for the response though.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thank you so much, I feel like an idiot but yea completely missed that.  Also, sorry about all the comment, tried to break the lines but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Typedef` your `struct` or specify `struct` in the functions for the `type`.

Also, your `struct` called `com_stack` does not have a member `stk` but does have a member `st`.

```
struct com_stack
{
  unsigned el_num;
  struct command *st;                                         
  unsigned top;
};

void com_push (struct com_stack* s, struct command input)  // <-- add "struct"
{
  if(s->top == (s->el_num - 1))
  {
    s->el_num+=64;
    s->st=(struct command*)realloc(s->stk,sizeof(struct command)*s->el_num); // <-- st, not stk and need "struct" here as well
  }
  s->st[s->top]=input; // <-- st, not stk
  s->top++;
}
```

Comment: Tried to upvote, but need 15 rep.  Thank you so much.  One missing point is that there needs to be struct for the casting as well.  Now hopefully my logic is correct for push function.

Comment: @Jack Keep coming back to StackOverflow and get more rep!

Comment: @CraigAnderson Thank you. I totally forgot about that.